# Install MSI packages with Powershell 2 on Win 2008

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008, uninstallation

My Powershell 2.0  script is installing an MSI package using something like the following excerpt.

```
(...)
msiexec.exe /norestart /qn /passive `
        /l*v "$Dir\Install.log" `
        /i "$dirTemp\$msi" `
        INSTALLFOLDER="$Dir"
(...)
```

It runs successfully, but I would like the script to wait for the installation to end before proceeding to the next instructions.
Is there a way to force the script to wait `msiexec` to finish?

***20220909 EDIT: Tried suggested answer*** ⬇️

As suggested, I've tried `Start-Process` as shown bellow.

```
$Dir = "c:\test"
$dirTemp = $env:TEMP
$msi = "package.msi"
$proxy = "1.2.3.4"
$metadata = "value"

$argList = @('/norestart',
            '/qn',
            '/passive',
            '/l*v',
            "$Dir\Install.log",
            '/i',
            "$dirTemp\$msi",
            "INSTALLFOLDER='$Dir'",
            "LOGFILE='$Dir\Agent.log'",
            "SERVER='$proxy'",
            "BUFFERFILE='$Dir\Agent.db'",
            "METADATA='windows $metadata'")
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "$argList" -Wait -PassThru
```

By using Start-Process, Windows Installer fails to start and only shows me the `msiexec` "*help*" window.

[image]

I could not find a syntax error.
Also, there's no logs to be found at the appointed log directory.

Thank you

***20220910 EDIT: Found the issue*** ⬇️

I had to change the single quotation marks from one of the parameters to a double quotation and scape them.

```
"METADATA=`"windows $metadata`""
```

It seems `msiexec` did not like the space inside the parameter's value.

Comment: You can try launching `msiexec.exe` with [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2) and the `-Wait` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS2 also has the cmdlet start-process if I remember correctly. There you can specify the parameter "-wait":

```
$argumentList = @(
    '/norestart'
    '/qn'
    '/passive'
    '/l*v'
    "$Dir\Install.log"
    '/i' 
    "$dirTemp\$msi"
    "INSTALLFOLDER='$Dir'"
)

$result = start-process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $argumentList -Wait -PassThru
```

Comment: I've tried to use `start-process` as suggested, but it could not start `msiexec`. I've edited the main question to expose this attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows Installer 1.0 was first released, msiexec.exe has always run in the Windows subsystem. That means that when it is executed from the console or by a batch script control returns to the console or script immediately.

In this scenario I like to use `start /wait` from the command line or a batch script. This will create the process and wait for it to exit, and the return code from the process is passed through and returned from the start command such that `%ERRORLEVEL%` is set accordingly.

`start /wait msiexec.exe` followed by your remaining parameter